# how to call method magento api

Tags: php, magento

im working with magento api, and i need verify my connect. 
how to call method APIauthentication with $client object? because im getting error on this: `Error: Function ("APIauthentication") is not a valid method for this service`

thanks for the help.

this is my class:

```
<?php

class Magento {

const PRODUCTS_LIST = 'catalog_product.list';

public function Verify( $data )
{

        $client = new SoapClient( $data['store_url'] );

        $verify = $client->APIauthentication( $data['api_user'], $data['api_key'] );
        if ($verify)
        {
            return $this->Register( $data['store_url'], $data['api_user'], $data['api_key'] );

        }
}

public function APIauthentication( $apiUser, $apiKey ) {

        $client = $this->_getClient();
        $token = $client->login( $apiUser, $apiKey );
        $this->_setToken( $token );

        return $this->_apiJsonResult( $token );
}
}
```

there is url:

```
$data['store_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/magento/api/soap/?wsdl';
```

firstly i need verify, second - get list:

```
// For products
public function getProducts()
{
    return $client->APIgetProductsList();
}

/*
     * Get product list
     */
    public function APIgetProductsList() {

        $token = $this->_getToken();
        $client = $this->_getClient();

        $products = $client->call($token, self::PRODUCTS_LIST );

        return $this->_apiJsonResult( $products );

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide (parts of) the contents of the WSDL in `$data['store_url'] ` assuming the URL is a WSDL, if not that is your error

Comment: If you can provide some more details about what do you want to achieve and which api you want to use.Then only you can get better help.

Comment: I see that you are calling `Magento::APIauthentication` as a function of `SoapClient` by doing `$client->APIauthentication`. SoapClient will try to match that to a API function defined in the WSDL and make a call

Comment: yes im calling SoapClient class method APIauthentication, but i need call magento method APIauthentication

Comment: Then use `$this->APIauthentication` instead

Comment: its works, than i change `$token = $this->_getToken();` to this `$client = new SoapClient( 'http://213.197.148.233:891/api/soap/?wsdl' );` in APIgetProductsList method. but how to change  `$client = new SoapClient( 'http://213.197.148.233:891/api/soap/?wsdl' );` this if i will not need write every time ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own api by creating new module then you can use that api method refer this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/custom_api_complete_example